# ETL Job that filters data based on Keywords in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to make Pentaho Kettle job which can do below ETL process:

Want to match Keywords from keywords.csv into the sentence column in data.csv and want to produce below output where all sentence won't be included where the keyword matches into the sentence.

I was able to do it in Talend but not able to achieve same in Pentaho Kettle. I tried to use Filter but it's not working.

I want to use keywords.csv as Input not fixed input in ETL job itself.

**keywords.csv**

```
apple
banana
orange
green apple
pineapple
```

**data.csv**

```
id,sentence 
1,This apple is nice
2,That is my truck
3,This building is beautiful
4,Apple and pineapple are good for health
5,that orange is fresh
```

**output.csv**

```
2,That is my truck
3,This building is beautiful
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this using the Fuzzy Match step in Pentaho. Anything that gets scored >0 could be filtered out.

Comment: Hi eicherjc, Thanks for reply but it's not working. See screenshots.  [FuzzyMatch](https://prnt.sc/p8t2fg)  and [Result](https://prnt.sc/p8t3d4) every line getting score >0

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a Java Script step where you load the keywords.csv data via the loadFileContent function and then loop through it's values.
Ultimately the JavaScript function will write a boolean variable (let's call it "include") to each row.
The next step is a 'Filter row' where you skip each row that has include=false.